# Scala map get several values if contains in map

Tags: scala

How to get several values from the Map if they exist?
For this I use the following code

```
val params:mutable.Map[String,String]=mutable.Map.empty
Seq(params.lift("Name"),params.lift("Surname")).flatten.mkString(" ")
```

But maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Maybe a for comprehension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure that it is what you want, but I think this modification of your second line is a little more readable:

```
Seq("Name", "Surname").flatMap(params.lift(_)).mkString(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in a comment, a for comprehension can get the job done as well. Depending on personal taste, either approach can be preferred:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

def multiget[K, V](map: scala.collection.Map[K, V], keys: K*): Seq[V] =
  for {
    key <- keys
    value <- map.get(key)
  } yield value

val data = mutable.Map("Name" -> "John", "Surname" -> "Smith")
multiget(data, "Name", "Surname").mkString(" ")
```